# GD PHP Rotate Image Black Border

Tags: php, gd, exif, image-rotation

I try to resize and rotate an image with PHP (GD) but when image rotate, it add a black border on right.

Exemple image (**before** resize & rotate):
[image: Exemple]

Exemple image (**after** resize & rotate):
[image: Exemple of black border add]

Here is my code :

```
    $image = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    if ($image) {

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);

        $i = strrpos($filename,".");
        $l = strlen($filename) - $i;
        $ext = substr($filename,$i+1,$l);

        $extension = strtolower($ext);

        if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") 
            && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) {

            echo ' Unknown Image extension ';
            $errors=1;
        }

        else {
            $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

            if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" ) {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
            }
            else if($extension=="png") {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
            }
            else  {
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
            }

            $max_width = 175;
            $max_height = 100;

            $size=GetImageSize($uploadedfile);

            $width_ratio = ($size[0] / $max_width);
            $height_ratio = ($size[1] / $max_height);

            if($width_ratio >=$height_ratio) 
            {
                $ratio = $width_ratio;
            }
            else
            {
                $ratio = $height_ratio;
            }

            $new_width = ($size[0] / $ratio);
            $new_height = ($size[1] / $ratio);
            $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);

            if(function_exists("exif_read_data")){
                $exif = @exif_read_data($uploadedfile);

                $rotateImg = imagerotate($src,0,0);

                if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
                    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
                    case 8:
                        $rotateImg = imagerotate($src,90,0);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $rotateImg = imagerotate($src,180,0);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $rotateImg = imagerotate($src,-90,0);
                        break;
                    } 
                }
            }

            imagecopyresampled($tmp,$rotateImg,0,0,0,0,($new_width-1),($new_height-1),$size[0],$size[1]);

            $filename = sha1(basename( $_FILES['file']['name']));
            $path = dirname(__FILE__)."/../files/pictures/".$filename;

            imagejpeg($tmp,$path,100);

            imagedestroy($src);
            imagedestroy($rotateImg);
            imagedestroy($tmp);


        }
    }
```

I tried some modification like the answers of this posts :
- [A border appears when rotating image with gd + php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205029/a-border-appears-when-rotating-image-with-gd-php)
- [PHP - Rotate image with GD gives black borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630725/php-rotate-image-with-gd-gives-black-borders)
- [Why when i rotate the image black borders appear? PHP GD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795638/why-when-i-rotate-the-image-black-borders-appear-php-gd)

But nothing work.

Please guys helps me.

Thanks you

Comment: Please edit your question to include the image before resize & rotate so that your code can be tested.

Comment: image before resize & rotate added ;)

Comment: Your code [works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRFQo.jpg), What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP Version 7.0.15

Comment: The image is uploaded from iPhone Library. Can you try with image from iPhone Library (picture portrait)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs if the EXIF data indicates rotation is necessary, because after the rotation the values of height and width are still treated the same. Since the image has been rotated these values should be switched with one another.

The rotation needs to be done first, not last, so move the rotation code above all of the ratio calculations (to just after you declare `$size`). You'll need to keep track of a 90/-90 degree rotation taking place:

```
$rotated = false;
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 8:
            $src = imagerotate($src, 90, 0);
            $rotated = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            $src = imagerotate($src, 180, 0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $src = imagerotate($src, -90, 0);
            $rotated = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Now you need to 'flip' the values if the orientation has changed:

```
if ($rotated) {
    $width = $size[1];
    $height = $size[0];
} else {
    $width = $size[0];
    $height = $size[1];
}
```

In the rest of your code replace instances of `$size[0]` with `$width` and `$size[1]` with `$height` to fix the calculations.

You could also `...($new_width-1),($new_height-1)...` to just `...$new_width, $new_height...` to make the resized image fit correctly, otherwise there is a 1px black border on the right and bottom of the resulting image.

Comment: Thanks you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

You should rotate the source image and not the resized version. Resizing after the rotation fixed my similar problem.